# Filling available space in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to render a list of items with Bootstrap. Each item will show an icon, some left-aligned content and some right-aligned content. It will look something like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|                    Peyton Manning                Denver  |
|  [vertically       QB                           Broncos  |
|   centered icon]   #18                                   |
|                    Tenesee                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|                    Andrew Luck             Indianapolis  |
|  [vertically       QB                             Colts  |
|   centered icon]   #7                                    |
|                    Stanford                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

In an attempt to do this, I was using a ul list-inline. The reason why is because the icon will be smaller. It won't take up a full bootstrap column. However, if I use the list-inline, I don't know how to make the other columns take up the remaining space. I was trying this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer" style="font-size:2.2rem; top:-10px;"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h4 style="margin-top:4px;">Peyton Manning</h4>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <h5>QB</h5>
            <h5>#18</h5>
            <h5>Tennessee</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
            <h5>Denver</h5>
            <h5>Broncos</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer" style="font-size:2.2rem; top:-10px;"></i>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h4 style="margin-top:4px;">Andrew Luck</h4>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <h5>QB</h5>
            <h5>#7</h5>
            <h5>Stanford</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
            <h5>Indianapolis</h5>
            <h5>Colts</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to include the icon and then grab the rest of the space such that I can left-align and right-align content in that space. Can someone please steer me in the right direction?

Thank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3 there are the `pull-left` and `pull-right` classes that float left and right respectively.

You can use those and the grid system of Bootstrap and with less markup achieve the desired result.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 text-center"> 
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-conifer product-icon"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <div class="pull-left">
                 <h5>QB</h5>
                 <h5>#18</h5>
                 <h5>Tennessee</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="pull-right">
                 <h5>Denver</h5>
                 <h5>Broncos</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.product-icon { font-size:2.2rem; margin-top:20px;}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hr9do3s9/2/) is a jsfiddle with a demo. I used only the col-xs-* but only to keep it simple.

**Edit**: To center the icon you can use the `text-center` class, also provided by Bootstrap. To vertically align the icon with CSS is not easily achievable since your main concern is that the `div.row` does not have a fixed height. So I gave it a small `margin-top` instead.